# Windows Server 2008 R2 editions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

What are the differences between the Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and Enterprise editions?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here, these should help you out

- http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-features.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-editions-overview.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx